# My website not refreshing after Facebook Login

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-login

I have integrated Facebook login in my [website](https://investlast.com), and it is working fine. But, when I successfully login via Facebook the **Sign In** box remains open, however, if I refresh my page then I see that I'm successfully logged in via Facebook.

This should not happen, the **signin box should close automatically** and the page should get refreshed automatically. Even the Twitter login is working fine as per expectations.

I tried adding below listener to my facebookauth.js file but it was of no use:-

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() 
{
window.location.reload(true);
});
```

I added above code under Init in the code :-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : facebook_auth.appID,
        status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
```

NOTE: I am using Wordpress and a theme called QA Engine, also if anyone trying to login via FB on my site to test then please provide any username & password on the sign in with Facebook that comes.

Comment: "provide any username & password on the sign in with Facebook" - why would you need username and password for a facebook login? the reason to use facebook login is not to need a password and stuff...

Comment: That's a bug or unwanted feature I received from my the WordPress theme that a first time user who signed in via FB, Twitter, Google will have to enter any username and password of his choice, I am trying to remove that by myself.
Plz ignore that.

Comment: One can ignore this text -> "also if anyone trying to login via FB on my site to test then please provide any username & password on the sign in with Facebook that comes."

Comment: ok, about your question in general: did you use some plugin for it? did you debug the FB.Event.subscribe callback? did you program it on your own? did you try with FB.login? why should the auth.login event be called? you should add the relevant code for the login, that would make it easier to help.

Comment: Hi @luschn,
No I'm not using any plugin for that FB login,

No, I didn't debug the FB.Event.subscribe callback, I just added it by my own to add a listener to refresh my page automatically after a successful login,

The Fb login thing was added default with the WordPress theme,

I have added that auth login event to just refresh my page automatically,

The whole code of facebook login code being used:-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VB18zVfAWsIXafsVjzafzXcmswZM1Fbd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `FB.getLoginStatus` right after `FB.init`, that´s the proper way to check for users who already are authorized with your Facebook App/Login:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Of course you can also use that function later, but make sure not to use `FB.login` in the callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`. `FB.login` needs to be called in a click event handler, not in an asynchronous callback.

Comment: window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 // init the FB JS SDK
 FB.init({
  appId      : facebook_auth.appID, 
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
 });
  // Check whether the user already logged in
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //display user data
            getFbUserData();
        }
    });
};

Comment: Hi, I tried adding FB.getLoginStatus like this (above), but it gave me no good result, still, the page doesn't refresh after successful Facebook signin.

Comment: what does "no good result" mean? please be more specific and add detailed debug info. dont just copy code, make sure you understand it, and debug stuff.